# Are RET and C-m really the same exactly?

Tags: emacs, keyboard

In the *graphical mode*, `RET` does the same as `C-m`, namely newline.

However, when I use `M-a` or `M-e`, they seem to distinguish between them. The newline produced by `RET`, they skip all to a double-RET point, and with the newline produced by `C-m`, they move the cursor line by line. Why so?

Description (`C-h k`) for both keys shows the same.

If it matters, it is Emacs23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Oh, is it supposed to move to Emacs SE, incidentally?

Comment: Emacs is on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **graphical mode**, the answer is *yes* (unless keys are redefined, of course).

Careful examination of my file showed that the effect I observed was a coincidence. It was exactly in those paragraphs which I `C-m`'ed that all lines would end in a dot (it was a poem).

Actually, `C-h k` key description says the same thing for both keys. Thanks to [schaueho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557416/2430544) for pushing me in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

The answer could be dependent on the mode you're in as well as in the key codes generated by your operating system. When I hit `Ctrl-h k Ctrl-m` in the `*scratch*` buffer on my Windows box, I'll get the info for `(newline)` with the information that it is bound to `RET`. Theoretically, in  some other mode, `C-m` and `RET` could be set to different functions. This requires, of course, that the OS doesn't generate the same key code.

Comment: Thanks! You made me look into the help and think some more. I edited the question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What Emacs writes as `RET` (or as `<RET>`) is, yes, the same character as `C-m` - it is the ASCII control character `13`. This is so regardless of what keyboard etc. you have.

However, the logical key (aka "key sequence") that Emacs sees when you hit the phisical (keyboard) key named `Enter` or `Return` might be different from `RET` (aka `C-m`). To see what key Emacs recognizes when you hit that keyboard key, use `C-h k` and hit the key. If Emacs says `RET` then this is the typical case, and yes, hitting that key is then identical to pressing `Control` and hitting `m` (assuming the key labeled `Control` does what it does typically).